# Recomeçar a contagem se exceder as opções

Tags: javascript, jquery

Esta pergunta provavelmente será respondida em menos de 5 minutos de tão fácil, mas eu estou quebrando a cabeça...

Vou simplificar muito aqui, mas acho que dá pra entender:

Crio elementos pelo javascript, cada um tem sua cor de fundo, são 8 cores que estão em classes. (.fundo1, .fundo2...).

Mas são apenas 8 cores, como faço para se criar mais do que 8 elementos a contagem volte a 0?

OBS: Sei que da pra fazer isso apenas de uma forma simples sem usar variáveis... Mas hoje não ta sendo meu dia nem aqui nem no tio google.

Código exemplo:

```js
$(function(){
  $("#adicionar").on("click",function(e){
    $("#teste").append("<div class='fundo"+ ($("#teste div").length+1) +"'></div>");
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
#teste div{
  float:left;
  clear: left;
  width:40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 2px;
}
.fundo1{
  background-color: #000;
}
.fundo2{
  background-color: #00F;
}
.fundo3{
  background-color: #0FF;
}
.fundo4{
  background-color: #F00;
}
.fundo5{
  background-color: #FF0;
}
.fundo6{
  background-color: #FA0;
}
.fundo7{
  background-color: #0F0;
}
.fundo8{
  background-color: #F0F;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="teste">
</div>
<a href="#" id="adicionar">Adicionar</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Se você não quiser as cores exatamente nessa ordem, pode gerar um valor aleatório entre 1 e 8:

```js
$(function(){
  $("#adicionar").on("click",function(e){
  var num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 8) + 1);
    $("#teste").append("<div class='fundo"+ num +"'></div>");
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
#teste div{
  float:left;
  clear: left;
  width:40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 2px;
}
.fundo1{
  background-color: #000;
}
.fundo2{
  background-color: #00F;
}
.fundo3{
  background-color: #0FF;
}
.fundo4{
  background-color: #F00;
}
.fundo5{
  background-color: #FF0;
}
.fundo6{
  background-color: #FA0;
}
.fundo7{
  background-color: #0F0;
}
.fundo8{
  background-color: #F0F;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="teste">
</div>
<a href="#" id="adicionar">Adicionar</a>
```

Comment: Obrigado, pensei nesta possibilidade também. Mas como são apenas 8 opções tem muita repetição e acaba ficando meio feio o resultado para o usuário, assim é só se exceder o padrão de 8 mesmo. (geralmente não haverá mais que 6, mas a gente precisa preparar para aquele usuário que abusa do bom senso hehe)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
  //cria uma variavel para saber qual a contagem
  var contador = 0;
  $("#adicionar").on("click",function(e){
    // alimenta + 1 na variável;
    contador ++;
    // se ela for mais que 8, volta a ter o valor 1
    if(contador > 8){
      contador = 1;
    }
    $("#teste").append("<div class='fundo" + contador + "'></div>");
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Comment: Valeu caio , mas não queria utilizar variáveis, eu lembrei como se faz, dei uma fuçada em uns códigos velhos aqui e me veio a luz na cabeça

Comment: Por curiosidade, pq sem variáveis?

Comment: eu estou criando um projeto e quero deixar tudo o mais simples possível, para que seja fácil a leitura e tentar de toda forma deixar o código curto.

Comment: Código sem variável não é necessariamente código mais limpo ou de fácil leitura, o não uso delas pode fazer justamente o contrário

Comment: Sim, além de gerar mais processamento.

Answer (score 0):

Então, acabei de lembrar como se faz, peço desculpas por tomar o tempo de vocês.

É só usar %, no caso:

```
var num=NUMERO_ATUAL % MÁXIMO;
```

Isso vai manter dentro do meu range máximo. Então seguindo meu exemplo:

```js
$(function(){
  $("#adicionar").on("click",function(e){
    $("#teste").append("<div class='fundo"+ (($("#teste div").length % 8)+1) +"'></div>");
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
#teste div{
  float:left;
  clear: left;
  width:40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 2px;
}
.fundo1{
  background-color: #000;
}
.fundo2{
  background-color: #00F;
}
.fundo3{
  background-color: #0FF;
}
.fundo4{
  background-color: #F00;
}
.fundo5{
  background-color: #FF0;
}
.fundo6{
  background-color: #FA0;
}
.fundo7{
  background-color: #0F0;
}
.fundo8{
  background-color: #F0F;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="teste">
</div>
<a href="#" id="adicionar">Adicionar</a>
```